# aplay finds no sound cards despite dtparam=audio=on

Tags: usb, audio, alsa

I broke my boot partition and had to rebuild it. Both cmdline and config.txt are gone and I had to start over. The rest of the system is untouched. Unfortunately, I forgot how they were configured and now aplay (and therefore mpd) find no soundcards.

I think I missconfigured my /boot/config.txt. My goal is to have a resolution of 800x480 60p and to have mpd as well as kodi use an external USB soundcard.

```
dtparam=audio=on

gpu_mem=128

hdmi_cvt=800 480 60 6
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
```

Unfortunately I still get no sound:
`sudo aplay -l` results in
`aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...`

Since I didn't touch any config files outside /boot, I think the error must be in the file posted above.

Update: I was able to reproduce the behavior on a different Raspi. There I backed up the files config and cmdline, but exactly the same thing happened.

Update: The USB-attached wireless keyboard is not working either. It may be an USB-related problem. What's strange is that all devices show up in lsusb.

What is the problem with it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Install updates again. The problem with MPD and the USB keyboard was due to a bug in a packet that got installed along with the update (maybe the kernel, but I don't know). It was unrelated to the boot files.
Today's updates solved the problem. Everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that your user belongs to `audio` group.
To check groups of the currently logged user:

```
groups "${USER}"
```

To add yourself to the `audio` group:

```
sudo usermod -aG audio "${USER}"
```

That probably needs relogging for the changes to take effect.
You can try once again list your sound-cards:

```
aplay -l
```

To test you have the access to a sound-card, you can play some noise:

```
# Be careful, this can be very loud, since its volume is 100%

aplay -s 5000 -c 2 -f S16_LE -r 44100 /dev/urandom
```

Comment: The problem was already solved, see other answer from 2016.

Comment: Hi, I don't help to solve only your problem, but others too… In your case the answer helped, but there are cases when you need to dig deeper.